# Snowflake nodejs driver CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the nodejs driver.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SCHEMA.TABLE (
  id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
  received_at DATETIME
);
```

I insert data to the table like this using squel.

```
const statement = squel.insert()
    .into('SCHEMA.TABLE')
    .set('ID', uuid())
    .set('RECEIVED_AT', moment().format('YYYY-DD-M H:mm:ss.SSS'))
    .toString()

  const queryResult = connection.execute({
    sqlText: statement,
    complete: (err, stmt, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
      } else {
        console.log(`${body.event} event is sent to Snowflake`)
      }
    }
  });
```

Last week this was working fine, I can insert without any error. But when I tried it again I keep getting the

```
Timestamp '2021-14-9 10:16:53.511' is not recognized
```

I tried doing this on snowflake's workspace

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (ID, RECEIVED_AT) VALUES ('fe12cef0-9d3e-489b-8658-00b302501123', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

and it's working.

The question how can I apply this statement on nodejs?

Comment: What is the version of node driver which is being used in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

I just put a default value for the datetime using this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SCHEMA.TABLE (
  id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
  received_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```